# Can SolrNet do exact field value matches?

Tags: solrnet

The one thing I can't find in SolrNet is exact field matches. So, if my field contains exactly "My Name is James Bond," then I'm looking for something like this:

```
new SolrQueryExactMatch("FieldName", "My Name is James Bond");
```

I'm effectively looking for SQL-like searching:

```
WHERE FieldName = 'My Name is James Bond'
```

I'm wondering if this is a function of indexing?  Do we index the field, but not tokenize it?  If "My Name is James Bond" was a single token, I'm wondering if that would have the same effect?

Does such a thing exist in SolrNet?

Comment: It's not up to the client. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175619/apache-solr-string-or-text

Comment: So a simple SolrQuery against a string field will do what I want?

Comment: yes, you could use a SolrQueryByField

Comment: Write this an answer so I can mark is as correct.  Or should I just close as a dupe of the question you mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to store the field as a `string` not as `text` and then use SolrQueryByField on the value.