# Indexing email ids in solr

Tags: solr, solr4

I wish to index email ids in SOLR but somehow it doesnt work.
My search has two parts. Auto suggest and text search.
Auto suggest works just fine when I use

```
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

but the when i search for an email id that is unique it gives multiple results. For e.g. `sameer.rao@xyz.com` is the entry
input: `sameer.rao`
output:

```
sameer1.rao
sameer.rao1
sameer.rao
```

Please help!

I have tried using standard tokenizer, but it only searches the phrases separated by delimiters. I also want to implement auto suggest which would return results on partial search.
sample:
ankarao.ka

must return ankarao.kale
            ankarao.kate
    The field names i have used are

I am then copying email id to the remaining fields. The description of field types is given below.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using text as field type for email id, instand of text  use string as field type for email in your schema.xml file.

Reason why you should use string is here :

[see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175619/apache-solr-string-or-text)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the tokenizer you are using [EdgeNGram](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory), which will stem your indexed results for a more fuzzy search, just like what you are getting back for similar results. Have you tried using the regular standard tokenizer? Like this:

```
<analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Comment: I have tried using standard tokenizer, but it only searches the phrases separated by delimiters. I also want to implement auto suggest which would return results on partial search.

Comment: Have updated the question with details of all the field types i am using.